# Design differences of tails and whonix concerning virtualization

Tags: virtualization, tor

Tails and Whonix both can run in VirtualBox. Tails doesn't recommends it for security reasons (https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/index.en.html), for Whonix it seems to be a standard mode of operation.

What are the design differences which makes Whonix more secure to use it together with VirtualBox in comparison to Tails?

See also:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others

Answer (score 3):

Different threat models.

Whonix (needs to) [assumes](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Pre_Install_Advice#Host_Security), that the host is safe. (Tails needs to assume this as well to some degree, because I suppose, many users are downloading and burning/installing Tails using their host, where malware could interfere.)

Tails is more focusing on being amnesic. Whonix is more concerned about [misbehaving applications and leaks](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#Protocolleaks). Therefore [Whonix is not amnesic](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Warning#Whonix_is_not_amnesic). While there is [no substitute for Whonix's lack of an amnesic feature](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_there_a_substitute_for_Whonix.27s_lack_of_an_Amnesic_feature_.2F_Live_CD.2FDVD.3F_Forensics.3F), [full disk encryption is recommended](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Advanced_Security_Guide#Full_Disk_Encryption). Each project made a trade-off. (It would be nice to combine both, but we're not there development wise.)

Full disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.